# Как изменить положение текста в php

Tags: php, html

как текст перенести на середину?

```
- if ($connection == true) 
{
echo 'Connect!';
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: добавьте в echo немного html на свой вкус

Comment: С помощью css-свойств.

Comment: было бы вам не сложно написать этот код, на ваш конечно вкус =) css не выходит

Comment: `echo 'Connect!';` => `echo '<center>Connect!</center>';`

Comment: я вставил 2 таких текста, как поместить эти 2 кода в одну строчку на сайте?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/hIbCUF1

Answer (score 2):

CSS

```
    .check {
        margin: 0 auto;
        text-align: center;
    }
```

PHP

```
 if ($connection == true) 
 {
    echo '<div class="check">Connect!</div>';
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Можете выводить в таком виде:

```
echo ("<center>Stastus database: Connect!</center>");
```